# How to insert decimal value from textbox into database with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server database and Windows Forms application. I have 2 textboxes and 1 combobox. Users inputs their name and working rate into the textboxes and they chose year from combobox. I try to insert those values into my database.

EX:

```
2018    Mike    39,72     WORKERS
```

In database:

```
year --> nvarchar(4)
name --> nvarchar(50)
rate --> decimal(18,2)
type --> nvarchar(50)
```

My code is like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO USERS(YEAR,NAME,RATE,TYPE) VALUES ('" + yearcombo.Text + "','" + name.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(rate.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + ",'" + "WORKERS" + "')", connection);
```

I get this error:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: I added an example of how the insert would be vulnerable to my answer, please have a look.

Comment: ***WHY*** do you store a year (which is **clearly** a numerical value) as `nvarchar(4)` ?!?!?! Use the **most appropriate** datatype - always - and here this would definitely be an `INT` (more than a `nvarchar(4)`) ....

Answer (score 11):

This kind of insert is vulnerable to injection and as you have already discovered it is hard to add values like decimal, DateTime, ... to add columns, use `Parameters.Add`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO USERS(YEAR,NAME,RATE,TYPE) VALUES (@year, @name,@rate,@type)", connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(yearcombo.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@rate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rate.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "WORKERS";
```

Imagine that somebody changes the yearcombo value (as simply as using inspect element in chrome for example) and set it to:

"2019,'a',1,'Something');insert into ARESTRICTEDTABLE(somefield) values('somecolumn'); update AnotherTable set SomeField = 'somevalue');, insert into users(year,name,rate,type),(2019,"

then your command text would be:

```
"insert into users (year,name,rate,type) (2019,'a',1,'Something');insert into ARESTRICTEDTABLE(somefield) values('somecolumn'); update AnotherTable set SomeField = 'somevalue');, insert into users(year,name,rate,type),(2019," ,'" + name.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(rate.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + ",'" + "WORKERS" + "')"
```

Comment: it gives me Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @DarthSucuk As i don't know your exact table structure, somethings might not match it. for example if year column is a nvarchar, you should change the first parameter like this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = yearcombo.Text;` and so on, check and make sure that your column types match the parameter type.

Comment: I fix it when I write 37,2 it gives an error but when I write 37.2 it inserts but the main problem is it stored with comma.How can I fix it?

Comment: just replace the comma with`.` before trying to convert it: `Convert.ToDecimal(rate.Text.Replace(',','.'), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`

Comment: it not fix it I did you said but now on it get 37,62 to 3762,00

Comment: what is the vlaue of rate.Text?

Comment: rate.text is 37,62 but it saved as 3762,00

Comment: if rate.Text is 37,62 then `Convert.ToDecimal(rate.Text.Replace(',','.'))` would return 37.62

Answer (score 7):

You should use **SqlParameter** with a query containing parameters :
It should be like this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO USERS(YEAR,NAME,RATE,TYPE) VALUES (@YEAR, @NAME, @RATE, @TYPE)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@YEAR", yearcombo.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", name.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RATE", Convert.ToDecimal(rate.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TYPE", "WORKERS"));
```

I didn't test it but it convert your parameter to a correct decimal for your query.
Also it is better to use SqlParameter for security issues (preventing **SQL Injection**)

Comment: it gives me Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.