# How can I store SQL Server query value to variable?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to sum all values of a column (`ttl`), and store result in a variable (sum), I tried some code snippets, but I didn't get any success.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select sum(ttl) from feereceipt where std_id = '"+ textBox1.Text +"'",con);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
     sum = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
     MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what is going wrong?

Comment: Anything wrong ?

Comment: What data type is `std_id` ?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you should close the connection after the loop, closing the connection inside the loop will cause an error:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    sum = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
    MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());              
}
con.Close();
```

1. Sum should return a single value, so you can simply get the value like this:

   ```
   int sum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
   ```
2. Adding a variable directly to query makes it vulnerable for injections. Use parameters instead:

   ```
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select sum(ttl) from feereceipt where std_id = @id",con);
   cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
   ```

Comment: no it should not, because he closes the connection inside the loop, in which the second time that it's being checked for `dr.Read()` it should raise an error

Comment: It won't loop a second time if it has one row. It is very sloppy, but it would technically work. Most likely the parameter is an int.

Comment: @Crowcoder, it checks to see if `dr.Read()` is true or not (that should be false as you know), but this time the connection is closed.

Comment: Right. I gotcha.

Comment: I have also added an example of injection can be made adding query this way in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260242/how-to-insert-decimal-value-from-textbox-into-database-with-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260242/how-to-insert-decimal-value-from-textbox-into-database-with-c-sharp)

Comment: int sum =  (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar(); returns , specified cast is not valid

Comment: @RadhaKhare what about it?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani , all is going well but, i am facing problem where i am passing querry result to variable , i tried what you suggested but i get error "specified cast is not valid"

Comment: isn't `int sum =   Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());` working?

Comment: if it doesn't work means that data type of `ttl` is not `int`, `float` may be

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, let me check

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, datatype of ttl is numeric

Comment: in know its numeric, but is it type of int, or it has a floating poin? like float, or real

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, finally 'int sum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());' worked